# Nothern Trust Payroll Scam?

Tags: scams

There is a man on instagam, who DM'd me claiming that there is a payroll situation going on and that if I do small tasks for him that he will add me on the payroll. All he needs is my mobile accounting log in and full name to add me to the pay roll. Is this a scam? It looks legit however I am still skeptical.

Comment: That muscle in your body that says "looks legit", kill that.

Comment: It's obviously a scam. Anything that looks like a scam, is a scam. Anything that smells like a scam, is a scam. Don't bother figuring out what the specific scam is in this case, what is more important is that you trust your gut here - you asked this question because you are concerned that it is a scam. Don't betray your own instincts for a chance at 'free money' which you know doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm curious. What about this looks legit to you?

Comment: I'm tired of questions asking about scams. If you have to ask, then YES it is a scam.

Comment: @NathanL tell me about it.  "Someone wants to give me free money, yet wants my account number.  Is it a scam?"  Say that out loud OP.

Comment: After reading posts here I am starting to understand both why people get scammed and why our election process is so irritating no matter who you are for they are playing to this mindset just like the scammers. Makes me concerned for the human race at times.

Comment: Why the down votes?  People need to see this.  Ignorance can be fixed.  People just need a chance to learn.

Comment: @ShadoCat DVs are probably because there dozens to hundreds of identical questions on Money.SE... the _Related_ list on the right as I type shows 10. Several examples from this list come up as you enter this question. Even if the OP wasn't sure this is a scam, they should have spotted that it's a duplicate question and that there are many existing answers.

Answer (score 16):

100% scam.  Northern Trust is a major bank; they are not going to hire people via Instagram, nor pay them under the table, they will hire people via their website.  And even if they were, they wouldn't need your bank account login; they would need your checking account number and routing number perhaps for direct deposit but not mobile banking.  Northern Trust has over [sixty jobs open](https://northerntrustcareers.com/latest-jobs) right now on their website, so there's no reason to think there is an arbitrary limitation on hiring or similar which could cause someone to try and hire outside the regular boundaries - but even then, they are *most certainly* not going to do things this way as a major bank and one that will have a huge amount of regulatory oversight.

NOBODY, ever, should need your mobile account login and password.  Even the bank itself should not ever request that or need it.  Period, full stop.